# classify location of the expiry date on drug label and lot number

Tags: classification

Is it possible that using the Machine Learning classification model we can classify/predict the LOCATION/ORIENTATION of the lot number and expiration date on different vials label?

If yes, possible approaches.

Update: So far what I have observed is with EAST model
https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03155

one can locate text in the scene and then use OCR s/w like Textract to read those locations. Now, the real challenge is when you have lots of text available in the image vertical and horizontal and when you don't know where the particular text would appear in the image like expiry date - Is it possible to train a system to give just one or two locations which will be expiry date and lot number?

The challenge here I feel is the location but what features we would take to train as it's just text. I feel it's a classification problem with supervised learning but I may be wrong. Comment?

Thanks

Comment: Tell me this is *not* another assignment dumped on an unsuspecting community.

Comment: Nope, this is a genuine problem I am trying to solve. I have researched EAST model and Textract and other research papers. I know what I am asking..

Comment: Consolation, at last! (What made me uneasy was *not* asking for the most promising approach, mentioning the above; but restricting the question to it and requesting a reasoning when suggested infeasible (we *can not*).)

Comment: It would help to tell us what approaches you've already researched and considered.  Provide a little background and make this useful and interesting for others.

Answer (score 0):

It seems plausible that it might be doable, using methods in the research literature on object detection and localization (Yolo, Faster R-CNN, etc.).  The only way to tell for sure is to acquire a large dataset of such images and try it out and see how well it works on your data.